# My selector lines are only displaying one line in my Pickers. I'd like them to be like how the date picker is

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

For some reason I can't seem to get both selector lines in my pickers to show. They only seem to show one but the date picker is fine.

[image: Here is an image of what my pickers currently look like.]

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var linePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var skuPicker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        linePicker.delegate = self
        linePicker.dataSource = self

        skuPicker.delegate = self
        skuPicker.dataSource = self

        //passed over from previous view
        var plantInfo = plantInformation

        let totalNumberOfLines = plantInfo!["lines"].count

        //populated the data        
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView.isEqual(linePicker)){
            return lineInfo.count
        } else {
            return skusForPickerLine.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.isEqual(linePicker) {
            return lineInfo[row].lineNumber
        } else {
            return skusForPickerLine[row].sku_value
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let selectedValue = linePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        skusForPickerLine = lineInfo[selectedValue].skuInfo
        skuPicker.reloadComponent(0)
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        // height of picker is 50
        return CGFloat(50)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just an artifact of running a scaled simulator on your Mac? Use a real iOS device.

Comment: Yeah @maddy you're right. (Feel dumb), I expanded the iPad emulator, therefore, zooming in on the spinners, and they're visible now.